# Spinner not showing dropdown view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am stuck with this issues.
I am using Spinner for showing different languages.But it is opening as a POP UP and i need to open it as dropdwon.
I don't want to use spinnerMode property of XML.

Comment: Have you used `dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`?

Comment: I have already used that,but having same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("None");
    array.add("Site Visit");
    array.add("Order");
    array.add("Meeting");
    array.add("Send Quotation");

    ArrayAdapter<String> sadapter;
    sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,array);
    spinRequestAction.setAdapter(sadapter);
```

This way you can make **`adapter for your spinner`**.

Comment: I am still facing same problem.Please help me.

Comment: what kind of problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code

```
String[] city_list = new String[3];
city_list[0] = "New York";
city_list[1] = "San Francisco";
city_list[2] = "Washington DC";

ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String> (getApplicationContext(),         
R.layout.spinner_item, city_list);

city_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
city_spinner.setAdapter(aa);
```

for additional help, you can refer  [here..](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/android-spinner-how-to-set-default-value.html)